# Tapestry override Authenticator

Tags: java, inversion-of-control, tapestry, tynamo

I am trying to use a custom authenticator for tapestry-security (*org.tynamo.security*).

I have a custom authenticator

```
public class EnvironmentalRealmAuthenticator extends ModularRealmAuthenticator
```

And in my module I override the default authenticator of Tapestry (`ModularRealmAuthenticator`):

```
public static void bind(final ServiceBinder binder) {

    binder.bind(Authenticator.class, EnvironmentalRealmAuthenticator.class).withId("EnvironmentalRealmAuthenticator");
}

@Contribute(ServiceOverride.class)
public static void setupOverrides(final MappedConfiguration<Class, Object> configuration, @Local final Authenticator override) {
    configuration.add(Authenticator.class, override);
}
```

However, this causes the cache to not be cleared on logout - I have the suspicion that this is caused by the way the `DefaultSecurityManager` of Shiro detects if the authenticator listens to logouts:

```
Authenticator authc = getAuthenticator();
if (authc instanceof LogoutAware) {
    ((LogoutAware) authc).onLogout(principals);
}
```

As the `EnvironmentalRealmAuthenticator` is bound as a Tapestry service, it is initially injected as a proxy and hence `authc instanceof LogoutAware` yields `false` - that's why the default `ModularRealmAuthenticator` is bound in a different way in the `SecurityModule` of Tynamo:

```
// TYNAMO-155 It's not enough to identify ModularRealmAuthenticator by it's Authenticator interface only
// because Shiro tests if the object is an instanceof LogoutAware to call logout handlers
binder.bind(ModularRealmAuthenticator.class);
```

However, when I try to override my `EnvironmentalRealmAuthenticator` that way

```
binder.bind(EnvironmentalRealmAuthenticator.class).withId("EnvironmentalRealmAuthenticator");
```

this results in the following exception:

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Construction of service 'ServiceOverride' has failed due to recursion: the service depends on itself in some way. Please check org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.services.ServiceOverrideImpl(Map) (at ServiceOverrideImpl.java:31) via org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.modules.TapestryIOCModule.bind(ServiceBinder) (at TapestryIOCModule.java:52) for references to another service that is itself dependent on service 'ServiceOverride'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I seem to have found a (rather hacky) way. Instead of overriding the `Authenticator` itself, I override the `WebSecuritymanager` instead:

```
public static void bind(final ServiceBinder binder) {
    binder.bind(EnvironmentalRealmAuthenticator.class).withId("EnvironmentalRealmAuthenticator");
    binder.bind(WebSecurityManager.class, EnvironmentalSecurityManager.class).withId("EnvironmentalSecurityManager");
}

@Contribute(ServiceOverride.class)
public static void setupOverrides(final MappedConfiguration<Class, Object> configuration, @Local final WebSecurityManager override) {
    configuration.add(WebSecurityManager.class, override);
}
```

That way I don't have to bind the `EnvironmentalRealmAuthenticator` with its interface. In order to be able to identify the new `Authenticator` I annotated the module:

```
@Marker(Primary.class)
```

The implmentation of the `EnvironmentalSecurityManager` then looks like this:

```
/**
 * Used to properly (and uniquely) identify the authenticator (without having to override it)
 */
public class EnvironmentalSecurityManager extends TapestryRealmSecurityManager {

    private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(EnvironmentalSecurityManager.class);

    /**
     * Mind the @Primary annotation, used to identify the EnvironmentalRealmAuthenticator
     */
    public EnvironmentalSecurityManager(final @Primary Authenticator authenticator, final SubjectFactory subjectFactory, final RememberMeManager rememberMeManager, final Collection<Realm> realms) {

        super(authenticator, subjectFactory, rememberMeManager, realms);
        logger.debug("Created EnvironmentalSecurityManager - class of authenticator is {}", authenticator.getClass());
    }
}
```

That way I can guarantee that the correct `Authenticator` is used without actually having to override it.

Answer (score 1):

I can't be sure without seeing the final version of your `setupOverrides` method that caused that exception.

But, have you tried this:

```
public static void bind(final ServiceBinder binder) {

    binder.bind(EnvironmentalRealmAuthenticator.class);
}

@Contribute(ServiceOverride.class)
public static void setupOverrides(final MappedConfiguration<Class, Object> configuration, EnvironmentalRealmAuthenticator override) {
    configuration.add(Authenticator.class, override);
}
```

Comment: This fails with the exact same exception (and also resembles my tries, except for the identification of the override)

Comment: :(  In this case, I'm sorry but I'm out of ideas.

Comment: just FYI: the error is likely because Tapestry is trying to realise the service in order to pass it as a parameter, and it needs ServiceOverrides for internal stuff. You might try to obtain the instance using `@Local EnvironmentalRealmAuthenticator override`, this worked for me. Or alternatively try to get the instance from the `ObjectLocator` directly, by injecting it as an argument and calling `objectLocator.getService(EnvironmentalRealmAuthenticator.class)`